# How to make the left operand of the operator << a function?

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading

```
void operator<< (const Integer& left, const Integer& right)
{
    cout << "\n: " << right.i;
}
```

can be accessed like:

```
Integer obj;
obj << 5 << 3 << 2;
```

Fine:

But `qDebug` works like `qdebug() << 2;`

Which means that the left operand of `<<` operator is a function.

What should be the syntax of a user defined function so that I can write:
`myfunc() << 2;`

Comment: it's not the *functions'* << operator which is called, but the one from the returned object.

Comment: In fact, your code would fail to compile; in order to be able to chain calls to `operator<<`, it must return a value that can be used as the first parameter to itself. Usually, you just return a reference to the first argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left operand is not a function, it is the value the function returns. Specifically, `qDebug()` returns an instance of [`QDebug`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdebug.html), which has some 20 overloads of `<<` defined.

Comment: Thus the function should return an object that has an `operator<<` function that behaves as desired.